# Django ManyToMany object saving to different database

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django app that uses multiple databases - one for each client. When saving new objects, I use the `.save(using=db)` to specify which database the object should be saved to.

**Models**

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)

class Dataset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    documents = models.ManyToManyField(Document, related_name="doc_datasets")
```

**Saving**

```
dataset = Dataset(name = "myDataset")
dataset.save(using = db) # Success! The object is saved in the correct database.

document = Document(name = "myDocument")
document.save(using = db) # Success! The object is saved in the correct database.
```

I am running into issues when trying to add a many-to-many relationship:

```
dataset.documents.add(document) # This attempts to save to a default database (non-client specific)
```

How do I specify the database when adding a related object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the database router. The fix was to disable a custom router I've made.